# Challenges with Private Property Access

Tags: php, class, private

```
class FtpConnection{
  public  $host     = '';
  public  $user     = '';
  private $password = '';

  public function ftpconn($host,$user,$password){
    $ftpConn = ftp_connect($this->host);
    $login = ftp_login($ftpConn,$this->user,$this->password);
    // check connection
    $msg = 'FTP connection has failed! Attempted to connect to '. $host. ' for user '.$user.'.';
    if ( $ftpConn && $login){
      $msg = 'FTP connection was a success.'; 
    }
    echo $msg;
    ftp_close($ftpConn); 
  }   
}

$newconn = new FtpConnection;
$newconn->host = 'XXXXX';
$newconn->user = 'XXXX';
$newconn->password = 'XXXXX';
echo $newconn->ftpconn($newconn->host,$newconn->user,$newconn->password);
```

Issue: I am unable to access private property within the public function. There must be a certain Fix to get the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign `password` like below due to its visibility set to `private`

```
$newconn->password = 'XXXXX';
```

Also it doesn't make sense to pass the object properties as `ftpconn` arguments

```php
echo $newconn->ftpconn($newconn->host,$newconn->user,$newconn->password);
```

Instead, you better set `host`, `user`, and `password` from the FtpConnection class constructor.

```
class FtpConnection{
  public  $host     = '';
  public  $user     = '';
  private $password = '';

  public function __construct($host, $user, $password) {
     $this->host = $host;
     $this->user = $user;
     $this->password = $password;
  }

  public function ftpconn(){
    $ftpConn = ftp_connect($this->host);
    $login = ftp_login($ftpConn,$this->user,$this->password);
    // check connection
    $msg = 'FTP connection has failed! Attempted to connect to '. $host. ' for user '.$user.'.';
    if ( $ftpConn && $login){
      $msg = 'FTP connection was a success.'; 
    }
    echo $msg;
    ftp_close($ftpConn); 
  }   
}

$newconn = new FtpConnection('xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx');
echo $newconn->ftpconn();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you set the Class property and accessing it on the Function, then the Parameter is Unnecessary,

You can flip the process by setting the property in the Class Function

```
class FtpConnection{
  public  $host     = '';
  public  $user     = '';
  private $password = '';

  public function ftpconn($host, $user, $password){
    // Set the property in the Function
    $this->host = $host;
    $this->user = $user;
    $this->password = $password;

    $ftpConn = ftp_connect($this->host);
    $login = ftp_login($ftpConn,$this->user,$this->password);
    // check connection
    $msg = 'FTP connection has failed! Attempted to connect to '. $host. ' for user '.$user.'.';
    if ( $ftpConn && $login){
      $msg = 'FTP connection was a success.'; 
    }
    echo $msg;
    ftp_close($ftpConn); 
  }   
}

$newconn = new FtpConnection;
// Removed set Class Property

// Change the `ftpconn` Parameter
echo $newconn->ftpconn('XXXXX', 'XXXX', 'XXXXX');
```